# Проблема с localhost

Tags: localhost, jekyll

Всем доброго времени суток. И так в чём вопрос, я работаю и постоянно меняю папки сайтов которые запускаю для локалхоста. Все сайты на jekyll, вопрос в том, что я удалил старые папки и тд но по итогу когда открываю `мойайпи:4000` всё-равно попадаю на старые сайты хотя их на пк и нету. Решил проблему поставив 4001 порт, однако пугает что старые сайты до сих пор стоят на том порте, значит они где-то хранятся и возможно еще и память жрут. Как их отключить полностью?  `netstat -ano | findstr :4000` выдает что нету ничего однако браузер говорит обратное и отображает идеально старый сайт даже ссылки кликабельны.

Comment: Из любого браузера открывается?

Comment: Только что проверил, оказалось что нет, только из Оперы

Comment: Попробуйте почистить кэш в Опере, скорее всего Опера просто закэшировала сайт.

Comment: Только что очистил, не помогло

Comment: Турбо-режим (есть же что-то такое в Опере?) отключен?

Comment: Отключил его, Опера предложила еще раз очистить кэш и всё исчезло, спасибо огромное